# How to scrape the button click text using selenium with node js as shown in the pic

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

[need to scrape the button click text as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr6yw.png)

I have tried below code after entering into the website.It is not able to scrape the text.

```
      //*[@class='']//*[text()='']
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below line of code :-

```
   var textPromise = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css(".concentration.ngbinding")).getText();
textPromise.then((text) => {
  console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: Iam getting error  webdriver.By.cssSelector is not a function

Comment: var textPromise = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("concentration")).getText();
textPromise.then((text) => {
  console.log(text);
});

by using this only Iam getting active button value . how to get all the six button values

Comment: For that first you need to take all pollutant.name in webelement list then iterate through it to get text from it